# how to get the expect value by using perl

Tags: regex, perl

In the array `@fruit`, there are many values. I want to search whether the line contains the values in the array.

I want to find out 'fresh apple' rather than 'apple. but my code will return both 'fresh apple' and 'apple':

```
my $line = "this is one fresh apple!";
my @fruit= ("apple","fresh apple","banana","fresh banana","rice");

foreach my $fruit(@fruit){

    if ($line =~ /$fruit/){
        print "$fruit \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, your `$line` string contains both `'apple'` and `'fresh apple'`, so both are returned. You might want to give more details on the rule that you want to implement in that case. And what if your line was `'this is one fresh apple and one fresh banana'`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. for my case, this will not happen. the data line will only contain one fruit in the array. and I just want to match the one as long as possible. meaning if it's fresh apple then return fresh apple rather than apple. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want when you have `('apple', 'fresh apple', 'apple juice')` and `"This is some fresh apple juice"`?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest approach is probably to a) sort your array so the longest strings appear first and b) stop searching once you've found a match:

```
my $line = "this is one fresh apple!";
my @fruit= ("apple","fresh apple","banana","fresh banana","rice");

@fruit = sort { length $b <=> length $a } @fruit;

foreach my $fruit(@fruit){

    if ($line =~ /$fruit/){
        print "$fruit \n";
        last;
    }

}
```

You can improve this by creating a single regex and avoiding the loop:

```
use feature 'say';

my $line = "this is one fresh apple!";
my @fruit= ("apple","fresh apple","banana","fresh banana","rice");

@fruit = sort { length $b <=> length $a } @fruit;

my $re = '\b(' . join('|', @fruit) . ')\b';

if ($line =~ /$re/) {
  say $1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just you need to put a check on one line.

```
my $line = "this is one fresh apple!";
my @fruit= ("apple","fresh apple","banana","fresh banana","rice");

foreach my $fruit(@fruit)
{
```

`Validate the array here` check the value `apple` or `space`

```
    next if($fruit=~m/^apple$/ || $fruit!~m/[ ]/);
```

`Skip the value of apple`

```
    if ($line =~ / $fruit/){
    print "$fruit \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But this code cannot be used for other scenarios.  for example. if this line contains "This is one fresh banana", then the output should be 'fresh banana' rather than banana. and imagining there are more than 1000 items in the array... Thanks.

Comment: and I also notice that if the $line = "this is one apple", and the above logic cannot return 'apple' which is not my expectation.... any more idea? Thanks.

Comment: As per your wish we have delivered... If you are changing the question sure answer not matched. –

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "longuest" match, one option is to track it while you walk the array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line =  "this is one fresh apple!";
my @fruit = ("apple","fresh apple","banana","fresh banana","rice");

my $res;
my $res_length = -1;

for my $fruit(@fruit) {
    next if $line !~ /$fruit/;
    next if length($fruit) <= $res_length;
    $res = $fruit;
    $res_length = length($fruit);
}

print $res, "\n" if $res_length > 0;
```